# Add Date and Time Values? & how to query from one query's results into another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, getdate

What I would like to accomplish is updating this query to be able to auto pull the the current day like  getdate function perhaps, so that the date wouldn't have to be manually updated daily.

```
use n

select id, type, name, log_time , start_time , documents_created , pages_created, processed, processed_time  
from N_LF_OCR_LOG 
where 
--name like 'C-INV00410249%' -- CI11667474 (6).pdf' 
log_time between  '2017-3-07 00:00:00.000' and '2017-3-07 23:59:00.000'   
and documents_created <> 0 
or  ( documents_created is null and log_time between '2017-3-07 00:00:00.000' and '2017-3-07 23:59:00.000'  ) 
order by log_time
```

Then from the executed results, I'd like another query to query those results to show when: 
Any Results from the TYPE column > named 'email ocr in type & universal production’
where the ‘documents_created & pages_created’ numbers do not match. (see picture below)

[image]

Also report if following those rows ‘NULL’ file is missing or less than 7 files.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your query.

Comment: I took the spaces out. It should be updated now. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to create a test case when you post on SO.
[Link to your SQL query](http://rextester.com/VGW11122) I modified your AND/OR boolean logic to what I believe you were trying to accomplish and added comments as well.

Adding the current date to the filters is done through the expressions:

- Midnight of today is created by converting getdate() to a date which drops the time portion

  CONVERT(date, getdate())
- 11:59PM of today is a little more complex, but basically converting a datetime to the float representation, dropping the time portion and adding the specific time of '23:59' back to it

  CONVERT(datetime,floor(CONVERT(float,getdate()))) + '23:59:00'

Part 2, I don't believe you need to create another query on top of the results to get what you are looking for.  You can simply add the additional conditions and you will be able to filter to the types you want with the created filters as well.

If you do want to query your results over again, you need to create a WITH clause and then you can perform the "second" query like this:

```
-- first query
WITH my_subquery as (
    SELECT 1 as num
    FROM tbl)

-- second query
SELECT max(num) 
FROM my_subquery
```

**EDIT**
As requested, [here](http://rextester.com/LGVV2483) is a link to the first query (without type filter and page created filter) and [here](http://rextester.com/QTVP39248) is a link to the second query (with type filter and page created filter).

Comment: Thanks! With part two. I’d like to pull the 
'email ocr in type & universal production’
documents_created & pages_created’
“attachment’
Lines when the documents_created & pages_created’ don’t match.

In a separate report. Because the would be running simultaneously

Comment: I'm not sure what you link is for.  Also remove the "use N" at the top of your query as you can't tell the online sql editor to use a specific database to execute the query.

Comment: The link in the post contains the query that you are requesting for part 2.

Comment: I have added two links to the post, they are almost the same, but you can run both queries separately for two reports if that is what you need.

Comment: oooh, my bad... So, Is there a way to do this without creating a table?

Comment: Don't copy the CREATE TABLE or the INSERT VALUES portion of the query.  Those are there so that you can actually run the queries right in your web browser and see that they are working.  Just copy from the SELECT.... portion.

Comment: if I wanted to add query if the documents_created is less than 2 AND pages_created greater than 2. then ----                                                           --Filter to rows where number of pages and documents created are not equal. would I add ' AND documents_created <2 and pages_created >2'

Comment: Yes, that would do what you want.